# Using CORBA with an embedded system

Tags: c++, interface, embedded, corba

I have been reading about CORBA lately and I'm considering it for an embedded system. The systems we have now communicate over Modbus. The host side software would will typically ask the embedded system for data by using calls like so:

```
double temperature = ReadRegister(142);
```

This means that both the developer for the embedded code and the host side application programmer needs to program against a pretty extensive list of registers for measurement and diagnostics data. It would be nice to get rid of this mapping of data and registers and just call GetTemperature(), without the number 142 existing at all.

Would CORBA be something to consider here, or should I look into other solutions entirely?

Comment: Are you talking about ModBus RTU ASCII on a RS485 or with TCP?

Comment: Honestly, while it might work, I think that CORBA is overkill for this kind of use case. I would rather take an approach to define an enum or similar with the available registers which you use both on the embedded side and on the client side. If you create a file which contains entries like `temperature=142` you could even take a code generation approach to automatically generate wrapper functions, like for the client side `double GetTemperature() { return ReadRegister(142); }`. If the actual numbers for the registers are aribtrary, you could even automatically generate a simple sequence.

Comment: I agree with @Andreas. Automatically generate the code from a description file. I - for instance - us Python pretty much for such stuff. Integrated in the build system, that will most likely be easier. Note that, you need some description for CORBA or any other ORB anyway. I know quite some customers, who started with an ORB, just to notice later that is tearing down performance and now use a code-generator approach happily. Note also, that whether an ORB is usable at all depends on your hardware's performance/RAM, etc. Instantly saying it _will_ work or is will _not_ is dishonourable imo.

Comment: Of course how good CORBA works depends on your hardware, but also how you use it. It is a powerful technology, but when misused it could be slow (as any other technology). C-ORBs can be very small, a CORBA C++ TAO server with some application functionality is around 1Mb which is huge in some domains and peanuts in others.

Comment: "If you only know hammers, every problem looks like a nail". @JohnnyWillemsen: "CORBA will **definitively** work ...". **That is just wrong!** 1MiB can be much too large. Most embedded systems. ModBus systems are mostly Cortex-M-class (ARM7, smaller ColdFire, etc.) based. If you are very lucky, they have 1MiB of _Flash_ and little RAM.

Comment: @LPs I'm using ModBus RTU ASCII on a RS485.

Comment: @Andreas The register values are hidden away behind enums today. The code generator approach is something I also have considered, but I wanted to investigate CORBA first. Thank you for your input on this, I'll stay away from CORBA I think.